# Can someone help me to get started in codename one?

Tags: netbeans, codenameone

I don't want to use the Codename One designer/gui builder, but I want to make my app with manual code. I have gained familiarity with Netbeans over the past three or four months, but when I opened a Codename One project I was confused and am not even sure where to start. This is some of the starting code when opening a new Codename One project:

```
public void start() {
    if(current != null){
        current.show();
        return;
    }
    Form hi = new Form("Hi World");
    hi.addComponent(new Label("Hi World"));
    hi.show();
}

public void stop() {
    current = Display.getInstance().getCurrent();
}

public void destroy() {
}
```

<strike>Does any one know where I can find a resource for the Codename One API?</strike> (found it) Can someone share some example code with working button on the start screen that takes the user to another screen that might have another button that takes them back to the start screen? (I think some example code would be very helpful to me in figuring out how to build my own application in Netbeans with Codename One.) Also, is there any better/easier way to build an app in Netbeans beside Codename One?

Please don't ask me to post what I have so far so you can help me, because I have nothing so far (in terms of code) -- only an idea of what I want the app to do.

Answer (score 3):

They are all in subversion.  You can check it out directly from Google code.

e.g. `svn checkout https://codenameone.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/Demos/`